# MQTT CONNECT header: how to define username and password?

Tags: tcp, mqtt, iot

I'm attempting to send data to a MQTT broker from a device with very limited capabilities, so I need to build up my request manually before sending it out through TCP/IP.

I understand the username and password are held in the message payload, but I don't understand how they are delimited.  The overall length is given in the header, but I can't see how this is broken down into distinct strings once it arrives at the broker.

Could someone help me with an example of a working CONNECT request and some explanation of how it's formatted?

This page gives an overview that seems to make sense, but lacks any example with username and password.
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-protocol-messages-overview/

The specification document doesn't seem very helpful either, but I may just not be taking it in properly.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#connect

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so do let me know if I've missed out anything or phrased my request incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at an old version of the spec.

The full up to date [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) for version 3.1.1 contains a definition of how the username and password  is to be encoded in this [section](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718016).

> Each of these strings is prefixed with a two byte length field that gives the number of bytes in a UTF-8 encoded string itself, as illustrated in Figure 1.1 Structure of UTF-8 encoded strings below. Consequently there is a limit on the size of a string that can be passed in one of these UTF-8 encoded string components; you cannot use a string that would encode to more than 65535 bytes.

So you have 2 bytes (making up a 16bit number) which make up the length of the string, followed by that many bytes containing the actual string.

Both the username and the password are transmitted in this format.

Comment: Thanks - that makes a lot more sense now.